# Convert numbers in string to string

Tags: strings, xstring, fmtcount

I store some strings in a variable `\def\nomVAR{A12Z4E}` and I want to create some other command using the content of `\nomVAR`. LaTeX doesn't accept to declare variable with number in its name. So the idea will be to convert all the number in the string using `\numberstringnum` command (`fmtcount` package). The `xstring` can extract some specific string in a string but I have to precise the position of each one.

Do you think it is possible to write a function to convert each number to a string in a string and to rebuilt it?

Thus `A12Z4E` will become `AonetwoZfourE`.

**MNWE**

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}

\def\nomVAR {A12Z4E}

\nomVAR

\numberstringnum{1}

\numberstringnum{\nomVAR} %not working

\end{document}
```

**SOLUTION** (thanks egreg)

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\nomVAR {A12Z4E}

\nomVAR

\numberstringnum{1}

\newcommand{\changestep}[2]{%
  \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\x}{#1}{#2}[\x]%
}
\newcommand{\changeall}[1]{
 % suppress expansions made by xstring
\StrSubstitute{#1}{0}{zero}[\x]%
\x
\noexpandarg
\changestep{1}{one}
\changestep{2}{two}
\changestep{3}{three}
\changestep{4}{four}
\changestep{5}{five}
\changestep{6}{six}
\changestep{7}{seven}
\changestep{8}{eight}
\changestep{9}{nine}
\x
}

\changeall{\nomVAR}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `xstring` it's easy to replace each `1` with `one` and so on. But I'm not seeing what's the aim of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it expandably, provided the string only has alphanumeric ASCII characters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\convertdigits}[1]{\expandafter\convert@digits#1\convert@digits}
\def\convert@digits#1{%
  \ifx#1\convert@digits
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\convert@@digits#1}%
}
\def\convert@@digits#1{%
  \ifnum9=9#1%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\convert@@digit#1}\convert@digits
}
\def\convert@@digit#1{%
  \ifcase#1%
    zero\or
    one\or
    two\or
    three\or
    four\or
    five\or
    six\or
    seven\or
    eight\or
    nine\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\myvar{A12Z4E}

\convertdigits{A12Z4E}

\convertdigits{\myvar}

\edef\myvartext{\convertdigits{\myvar}}
\texttt{\meaning\myvartext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different `expl3` implementation: the argument to `\convertdigits` is fully expanded before being examined and scanned item by item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertdigits}{m}
 {
  \guuk_convertdigits:e { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \guuk_convertdigits:n
 {
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \guuk_digit:n
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \guuk_convertdigits:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \guuk_digit:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {0}{zero}
    {1}{one}
    {2}{two}
    {3}{three}
    {4}{four}
    {5}{five}
    {6}{six}
    {7}{seven}
    {8}{eight}
    {9}{nine}
   }
   {#1}% not a digit
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\myvar{A12Z4E}

\convertdigits{A12Z4E}

\convertdigits{\myvar}

\edef\myvartext{\convertdigits{\myvar}}
\texttt{\meaning\myvartext}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I set up a tokencycle to look (token by token) for letters (catcode 11) and numerical digits.  Anything else is discarded.  Digits are processed via `\spelldigit`, which executes a simple `\ifcase`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\numberstringnum[1]{%
  \resettokcycle
  \Characterdirective{\tctestifcatnx A##1{##1}{\spelldigit##1}}%
  \expandafter\tokcyclexpress\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand\spelldigit[1]{%
  \ifcase\numexpr`#1-`0 zero\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or
  six\or seven\or eight\or nine\fi}
\begin{document}
\def\nomVAR {A12Z4E}

\nomVAR

\numberstringnum{\nomVAR} 

\numberstringnum{AB23z0BN56q}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to be able to use the string to build a command, for example, this variant does not output the result, but instead stores it in `\thestring`, which can be subsequently used, as shown in this MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\numberstringnum[1]{%
  \Characterdirective{\tctestifcatnx A##1{\addcytoks{##1}}%
    {\addcytoks[x]{\spelldigit##1}}}%
  \Groupdirective{}%
  \Macrodirective{}%
  \Spacedirective{}%
  \expandafter\tokcyclexpress\expandafter{#1}%
  \edef\thestring{\the\cytoks}%
  \expandafter\def\csname\thestring\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
    {#1}}
\newcommand\spelldigit[1]{%
  \ifcase\numexpr`#1-`0 zero\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or
  six\or seven\or eight\or nine\fi}
\begin{document}
\def\nomVAR {A12Z4E}

\numberstringnum{\nomVAR}
\textbackslash\thestring=\csname\thestring\endcsname

\numberstringnum{AB23Z0BN56Q}
\textbackslash\thestring=\csname\thestring\endcsname
\end{document}
```

[image]