# How to use number to text conversion functions in TikZ multipart shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, fmtcount

I would like to use `foreach` constructions to draw lines between multipart nodes. But I find the problem that multipart `anchors` are declared with a textual names: `one, two, ...` instead of numbers.

I've tried to use conversion functions from `fmtcount` or `numname` packages but although they work inside node's text, I'm not able to use for anchors reference. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, positioning}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    my shape/.style={
          rectangle split
        , rectangle split parts=#1
        , draw
        , anchor=center
        }
    ]
\node[my shape=3] (main){
    \numberstringnum{1} 
   \nodepart{two}
   \numberstringnum{2} 
   \nodepart{three}
   \numberstringnum{3}};

\node[my shape=3, right=2cm of main] (second)
{
    \numberstringnum{1} 
   \nodepart{two}
   \numberstringnum{2} 
   \nodepart{three}
   \numberstringnum{3}};    

\draw (main.one east) -- (second.two west);
%following lines fail.
%\draw (main.\numberstringnum{2} east) -- (second.\numberstringnum{3} west);
%\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
%   \draw (main.\numberstringnum{\i} east) -- (second.\numberstringnum{\i} west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the macro  is not expandable (I didn't check) but you can basically define a simple switch and then it works

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, positioning}

\def\numname#1{%
  \ifcase#1zero\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\fi%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  my shape/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1 , draw, anchor=center}]

\node[my shape=3] (main){\numname{1}\nodepart{two}\numname{2}\nodepart{three}\numname{3}};

\node[my shape=3, right=2cm of main] (second)
       {\numname{1}\nodepart{two}\numname{2}\nodepart{three}\numname{3}};

\draw (main.one east) -- (second.two west);
\draw (main.{\numname{2} east}) -- (second.\numname{3} west);
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
   \draw (main.\numname{\i} east) -- (second.\numname{\i} west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick. It will be enough for me.

Comment: @Ignasi I've found this as an expandable alternative https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279954/ which looks like the same thing with more sophistication