# How to convert the last number of the ref command output to string

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals, strings

There is an answer explaining how to convert numbers to text [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279954/convert-numbers-in-string-to-string). But if I use a `\ref` output in the command `\convertdigits`, it throws the error `Missing number, treated as zero.` even if the ref output is a one-digit number. The code below is taken from that site.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\convertdigits}[1]{\expandafter\convert@digits#1\convert@digits}
\def\convert@digits#1{%
  \ifx#1\convert@digits
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\convert@@digits#1}%
}
\def\convert@@digits#1{%
  \ifnum9=9#1%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\convert@@digit#1}\convert@digits
}
\def\convert@@digit#1{%
  \ifcase#1%
    zero\or
    one\or
    two\or
    three\or
    four\or
    five\or
    six\or
    seven\or
    eight\or
    nine\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{a}
\subsection{a1}\label{key}
\subsection{a2}
\section{b}
\subsection{b1}
\subsection{b2}
\subsubsection{b3}
\ref{key}

\def\myvar{2}

\convertdigits{2}

\convertdigits{\myvar}

\convertdigits{\ref{key}} % ERROR

\end{document}
```

My question: Can I convert the last digit of the `\ref{key}` to string.
For example, if

the output of `\ref{key}` is `2.3`

then

the output of `\convertdigits{\ref{key}}` should be `three`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
{\def\hbox#1{}\def\protect#1\empty{??}\xdef\reftext{\ref{key}\empty}}
\convertdigits{\reftext}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the macro `\getrefbykeydefault` from the refcount-package for extracting that sequence of tokens that yield the text-string of the reference.

Assuming that expansion will not significantly change that sequence, you can take these tokens for a list of `.`-separated elements and extract the last one thereof. *(When writing "significantly change that sequence" I think about scenarios like expansion leading to the removal of some of the dot-separated elements.)*

If it is ensured that expanding the last dot-separated element yields only a valid *⟨number⟩*-quantity denoting a non-negative number, it can be "fed", e.g, to the `\numberstringnum`-macro of the fmtcount-package.

With the example below checking whether expanding it yields only a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity denoting a non-negative number is omitted because no such test is known to me which is not flawed in some way.

*(Any such test must be flawed/ will work out only for some restricted subset of possible user-input:*

*When attempting to implement an algorithm for such a test, then you are facing the halting-problem:*

*At the time of expanding them, the tokens forming the last dot-separated element of the text-string of the reference may form an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm. Having an algorithm check whether such an algorithm in the end yields a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity (denoting a non-negative number) implies having an algorithm check whether an other arbitrary algorithm  terminates at all/terminates without error-messages. This is the halting-problem. Alan Turing proved that it is not possible to implement an algorithm which for any arbitrary algorithm can "decide" whether that algorithm will ever terminate.)*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}%
}%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbletofirstdot{\long\def\UD@gobbletofirstdot#1.{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@keeptofirstdot{\long\def\UD@keeptofirstdot#1.{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}
\newcommand\extractlastdotitem[3]{\romannumeral0\extractlastdotitemloop{#1.}{#2}{#3}}%
\newcommand\extractlastdotitemloop[3]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletofirstdot#1}{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\@gobble\UD@keeptofirstdot\relax#1}{ #2}#3%
  }{%
    \expandafter\extractlastdotitemloop\expandafter{\UD@gobbletofirstdot#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\convertdigitsoflabel[1]{%
  \IfRefUndefinedBabel{#1}{\@ifundefined{hyperref}{\ref}{\ref*}{#1}}{%
    \begingroup\protected@edef\@tempa{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{}{0}}%
    \expandafter\extractlastdotitem\expandafter{\@tempa}{\endgroup\numberstringnum}{[m]}%
   }%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{a}
\subsection{a1}\label{a1}
\subsection{a2}
\subsection{a3}
\subsection{a4}
\subsection{a5}
\subsection{a6}
\subsection{a7}
\subsection{a8}
\subsection{a9}
\subsection{a10}
\subsection{a11}\label{a11}
\section{b}
\subsection{b1}
\subsection{b2}
\subsubsection{b3}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

\ref{a1}

\ref{a11}

\convertdigitsoflabel{a1}

\convertdigitsoflabel{a11}

\hyperref[{a1}]{\convertdigitsoflabel{a1}}

\hyperref[{a11}]{\convertdigitsoflabel{a11}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `refcount` and its expandable `\getrefnumber`.

In order to isolate the final part of the input string, you can use `\regex_split:nnN` that will store the parts separated by periods into different items of a sequence and take the last item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{refcount}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\convertdigits}{m}
 {
  \mert_convertdigits:e { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mert_convertdigits:n
 {
  \regex_split:nnN { \. } { #1 } \l__mert_convertdigits_seq
  \__mert_digit:e { \seq_item:Nn \l__mert_convertdigits_seq { -1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mert_convertdigits:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__mert_digit:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {0}{zero}
    {1}{one}
    {2}{two}
    {3}{three}
    {4}{four}
    {5}{five}
    {6}{six}
    {7}{seven}
    {8}{eight}
    {9}{nine}
   }
   {#1}% not a digit
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mert_digit:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{a}
\subsection{a1}\label{key}
\subsection{a2}
\section{b}
\subsection{b1}
\subsection{b2}\label{key2}
\subsubsection{b3}

\ref{key}, \ref{key2}

\def\myvar{2}

\convertdigits{2}

\convertdigits{\myvar}

\def\myvar{2.3}

\convertdigits{\myvar}

\convertdigits{\getrefnumber{key}}

\convertdigits{\getrefnumber{key2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to continue to use `\ref` in that context, you can change the main definition to

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\convertdigits}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \ref \getrefnumber
  \mert_convertdigits:e { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }
```